# Can you get an ideal route of multiple destinations using a single API call?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to see if there's a way in a single API call to find the ideal route, order not mattering, between X destinations.

For example, the program has 3 destinations, Jeff's house, Amy's house, and Valerie's house. Don't really care the order we go in, but we'd like to visit each house with the least amount of driving.

Right now, I have it set up such that we try every ordering of destinations, and settle on the one with the fastest time. But having so many API calls seems inefficient, but I can't see a way in the API to do what I want. Is what I want presently possible in the google maps API?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[Waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints)** in Directions API web service which returns a route that includes pass throughs or stopovers at intermediate locations.

> By default, the Directions service calculates a route through the
>   provided waypoints in their given order. Optionally, you may pass
>   `optimize:true` as the first argument within the waypoints parameter to
>   allow the Directions service to optimize the provided route by
>   rearranging the waypoints in a more efficient order.

Sample request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?
origin=Adelaide,SA&destination=Adelaide,SA
&waypoints=optimize:true|Barossa+Valley,SA|Clare,SA|Connawarra,SA|McLaren+Vale,SA
&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Note that requests using waypoint optimization are billed at a [higher rate](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use#directions-advanced).

If you will be using client-side Maps JavaScript Directions Service. Refer to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints) and [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints).

Hope this helps!